# The Alter Rebbe and Parshas Pekudei

Tags: messiah, chassidic-rebbe, pekudei, prognostications

This Shabbos we are reading the Torah portion of Vyahkeil-Pekudei. I read the following on a blog [here](http://shiratdevorah.blogspot.com/2014/09/5775-alter-rebbes-prediction.html?m=1) and [here](http://hezbos.blogspot.com.au/2014/06/rumor-re-5775.html):

Once, when the Alter Rebbe was the ba'al koreh, he read a verse slightly incorrectly. Instead of reading 1775 he read 5775.  He did so several times and was corrected each time. This was in Parshas Pekudei 38:28, which mentions the sum of 1775 talents collected.

> ואת האלף ושבע המאות וחמשה ושבעים

Instead of reading the "hei" of "ha-elef" (the thousand) with a "patach", he read it with a "tzeirei" (which turns the letter "hei" into 5).

When the 4th time occurred, he walked away and someone else finished the reading. When subsequently asked by the Mitteler Rebbe as to why and what had happened, he responded that at the time he saw a vision that Moshiach would come in 5775. He couldn't read it any other way.

This seems to have been reported by the Mitteler Rebbe even in his Sefer Imrei Bina (some say it was edited and then reinserted). Rabbi Leibel Groner quite a few years ago asked the Rebbe about it and whether he could confirm the story. He did.

He then asked if he could publicize it and the Rebbe said yes. Yet Rabbi Groner never has, until now. His reason for not doing so at the time was because the Rebbe was then coming out with the call of We Want Mashiach Now and that at any moment Mashiach could come.

As such, he felt uncomfortable to publicize this story then. Now, it seems, as we approach 5775, he revealed this conversation he had with the Rebbe and is publicizing it finally.

1) Can we calculate the date of the Final Redemption?

2) Since the Alter Rebbe is not a *Novi*, should we believe him?

3) How do view this story?

P.S. Rav Moshe Wolfson speaks about the year [5775](http://www.torahanytime.com/video/teshuvah-5775-the-year-of-the-geulah/). So does [Harav Ginsburgh](http://hezbos.blogspot.com/2014/11/has-time-for-redemption-arrived.html).

Comment: Even if you read it hei, there is no word hei that means five in the Torah. Why not assume it's English and Hashem is getting our attention 'hey' one thousand etc... And besides, even if it alludes to this year parshas Vayakhel pikudei, the only things predicted to appear are vavs, which we should subsequently cover the heads of which.

Comment: Well, it didn't come true.

Comment: I have never seen or heard of such a story from Rabbi Groner himself. I would be inclined not to believe the report on the blog. But in context, if Rabbi Groner publicized such a story, it would seem reasonable to ask him what he makes of it now in 5778.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Can we calculate the date of the Final Redemption?

We for sure can't.

2) Since the Alter Rebbe is not a Novi, should we believe him?

We can believe him that it is an opportune time for it to perhaps finally happen.

3) How do view this story?

The same way all other stories where one predicted it may happen. Remember the story in the Gemara of "Hayom" Im B'Kolo Tishmau.

This is in one of the links you linked to.

> Many such predictions of the date of the final Redemption have already
>   been and gone, and we have arrived at the 5775th year since the
>   world’s creation and Mashiach has not yet come. But, if we do things
>   right, this year could be a very auspicious one. It might even be the
>   year of the final redemption! - See more at:
>   http://hezbos.blogspot.com/2014/11/has-time-for-redemption-arrived.html#sthash.ZZhNWs6G.dpuf