# The Chofeitz Chayim on World War Three

Tags: sources-mekorot, messiah, shmita, prognostications, army-military-war

I read the following:

בְּשֵׁם הֶ'חָפֵץ חַיִּים' כָּךְ בִּשְׁנַת תשע"ה 75 שָׁנָה אַחֲרֵי פְּרוֹץ הַשְּׁנִיָּה צְפוּיָה לִפְרֹץ הַמִּלְחָמָה הַשְּׁלִישִׁית

שָׁמַעְתִּי מֵהגה"צ ר' צְבִי מֵאִיר זִילְבֶּרְבֶּרְג שליט"א (ניתן לשמוע ב'קול הלשון' שיעור מספר 27 הכנה לזמן חורף תשע"ה) שֶׁאָמַר שֶׁשָּׁמַע מִיּהוּדִים (שמע מהג"ר אברהם פאם זצ"ל ראש מועצת גדולי התורה באמריקה) שֶׁשָּׁמְעוּ מֵהַג"ר אֶלְחָנָן וַסֶּרְמַן הי"ד שֶׁדִּבֵּר בְּארה"ב בִּשְׁנַת תרצ"ט בְּעֶרֶב הַשּׁוֹאָה וְאָמַר לָהֶם בָּזֶה הַלָּשׁוֹן: **"קִבַּלְתִּי בְּרוּחַ הַקֹּדֶשׁ שֶׁאָנוּ עוֹמְדִים לִפְנֵי מִלְחָמָה נוֹרָאָה שֶׁתִּסְתַּיֵּם בִּשְׁנַת תש"ה, וְאַחֲרֶיהָ יָבֹאוּ עֶשֶׂר שְׁמִיטוֹת שֶׁל הֲכָנָה לַמָּשִׁיחַ, וּבִגְמַר הָעֶשֶׂר שְׁמִיטוֹת שֶׁמִּסְתַּיְּמוֹת בִּשְׁנַת תשע"ה זֶהוּ זְמַן בְּעִתָּהּ שֶׁמָּשִׁיחַ חַיָּב לָבֹא".** דְּבָרִים מֵעֵין אֵלּוּ נֶאֶמְרוּ עַל יְדֵי הַג"ר יוֹסֵף בֶּן פּוֹרָת שליט"א בְּשֵׁם הֶ'חָפֵץ חַיִּים' (הובא במוסף 'שבת קדש' של 'יתד נאמן' לך לך תשע"ה) שֶׁהֶ'חָפֵץ חַיִּים' אָמַר בִּזְמַן מִלְחֶמֶת הָעוֹלָם הָרִאשׁוֹנָה שֶׁ25 שָׁנִים אַחֲרֶיהָ תִּפְרֹץ מִלְחָמָה שֶׁהָרִאשׁוֹנָה תִּהְיֶה מִשְׂחַק יְלָדִים לְעֻמָּתָהּ, וְ75 שָׁנִים לְאַחֲרֶיהָ תִּפְרֹץ מִלְחָמָה שְׁלִישִׁית גְּדוֹלָה מִכֻּלָּן, שֶׁגַּם הַשְּׁנִיָּה תִּהְיֶה מִשְׂחַק יְלָדִים לְעֻמָּתָהּ, וְאָז יָבֹא מָשִׁיחַ. וּכְשֵׁם שֶׁמִּלְחֶמֶת הָעוֹלָם הַשְּׁנִיָּה פָּרְצָה 25 שָׁנָה אַחֲרֵי פְּרוֹץ הָרִאשׁוֹנָה, כָּךְ בִּשְׁנַת תשע"ה 75 שָׁנָה אַחֲרֵי פְּרוֹץ הַשְּׁנִיָּה צְפוּיָה לִפְרֹץ הַמִּלְחָמָה הַשְּׁלִישִׁית. מאת: מערכת סוד החשמל

תוספת מאת: א.ט ומעניין שדווקא בשנת תרצ"ט (השנה שהחפץ חיים דיבר) נולד מלך פרס חמינאי מנהיג אירן שעתיד להתגרות במלך הערבי ולעורר את פרוץ מלחמת העולם השלישית… חמנאי יהיה השנה בן 76  כמניין = בן דויד

Does anyone know where this original letter came from? Or whether it's valid or not?

Comment: I heard R' Matisyahu Solomon quote this as a Kabbalah from the Chofetz Chaim.

Comment: I've heard this from a few rabbis too. It was a secret kabbala. Guess the secrets out!

Comment: By "make WW2 look like 'child's play'", could he refer to (chav"ch) full-blown nuclear war?

Comment: after the shmita year? not much time is left. 4-5 months. what could be worse for the jews than wwII?

Comment: from what I've read of Rabbi Elchonon's works it seems to me he believed Moshiach would come during or just after the WWII. so that conflicts with this story that he had a kabala from the chofetz chaim. could be just another rumor

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you read? I read it too, but only because you posted it here... :D

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56413/the-alter-rebbe-and-parshas-pekudei

Comment: @LN6595 you heard this personally from Rabbi Mattisyahu solomon? if yes, that he received this from the chofetz chaim or from someone else such as rabbi elya lopian z'l

Answer (score 2):

No idea where it comes from, but in terms of validity, it at least has a math problem.

It is saying 25 years after WWI there will be a bigger war. And then 75 years after that will be a bigger one.

But the only way you get 25 years from WWI to WWII is 1914-1939. That works out in the Hebrew Calendar (other than the fact than 1939 is a rather arbitrary start date for a prediction of this nature since it is a post-hoc political view of when the war started) because September 1 1939 is in Elul 5699. Add 75 years from there, then you are in 5774 - last year.

There are other problems, such as not counting WWII from Germany's annexation of Austria, a year earlier. You could then count WWI from the Second Balkan War (also a year earlier - it motivated the famous assassination), which more firmly puts this date in the past, but I think the above math problem makes the prediction tenuous at best at this point.

Comment: Doesn't it say 10 Shmittot from 5705? That seems pretty unambiguous about the years (at least for the second time period).

Comment: It says two different things from two different sources. I addressed one (there was no bolding when I wrote my answer).

Comment: Bolding doesn't mean they weren't there :)